# Get a Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I create a app use react-cli,then import the material-UI,just a simple code

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Appbar from './Componets/Appbar/Appbar'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Appbar />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Appbar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppBar,Toolbar,Typography } from '@material-ui/core'
function Appbar(){
    return (
        <AppBar>
            <Toolbar>
                <Typography variant="h5" color="inherit">
                    BLACKPINK HOUSE
                </Typography>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    )
}
//before
export default AppBar

//after 
export default Appbar
```

I also modify the dependencies of node

```
{
  "name": "news",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "16.13.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
 },
```

It just can't start, if i remove the Appbar inside the App, it will run

the error message goes like this

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Module../src/index.js
C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/MaterialUI/news/src/index.js:7

```
   4 | import App from './App';
   5 | import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
   6 | 
>  7 | ReactDOM.render(
   8 |   <React.StrictMode>
   9 |     <App />
  10 |   </React.StrictMode>,
```

**webpack_require**
C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/MaterialUI/news/webpack/bootstrap:784

```
  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;
```

fn
C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/MaterialUI/news/webpack/bootstrap:150

```
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
```

**webpack_require**
C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/MaterialUI/news/webpack/bootstrap:784

```
  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;
```

checkDeferredModules
C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/MaterialUI/news/webpack/bootstrap:45

```
  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 |
```

Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push]
C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/MaterialUI/news/webpack/bootstrap:32

```
  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;
```

Comment: I'm also not seeing material-ui in your dependencies. Did you install material-ui according to the instructions? (i.e. npm install @material-ui)

Comment: Provide the file structure for your project